# Since the price of ETH has gone up 10x in 6 months, should I be lowering the gas price for my transactions?

Tags: gas, gas-price, price

The price of ETH has gone from ~8 USD/ETH to ~90 ETH/USD in 6 months, but when I view transactions on the blockchain ([example](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd4b4568663e00131f0c22e615fdc43eaeab9aba0a9ddd59dad305d1227c7c030)), I see that most people are still using the default gas price of 2e10 wei/gas.

Shouldn't we be lowering the gas prices on our transactions to account for this price change?

I have built a Dapp where low transaction fees are an important  selling point. I intend to drop my gas price to 5e9 (a 75% reduction). Will my transactions still clear in a timely fashion?

UPDATE: I have been running transactions (as of May 5 2017) with a gas limit of 2e9 gas and they have been clearing in ~7 min.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely. Everyone should.

There's a great site here that will help you understand gas and gas prices. It's called [Ethereum Gas Station](http://ethgasstation.info/). I'm not sure who publishes it, but it's very well done.

They just recently made this post which explains something they call the [Safe Gas Price](https://medium.com/@ethgasstation/the-safe-low-gas-price-fb44fdc85b91).